# Adding list of list contents to produce single list

Tags: list, haskell, anonymous-function

I have this

```
(map . map) (\x y -> x + y) [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

and the output I'm hoping for is

```
[5,7,9]
```

However, I get the error

```
* No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
         arising from a use of `print'
         (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
     * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Not sure how to proceed. I realize that the type I'm using with composition of `map` is

```
(map . map)     :: (a -> b) ->  [[a]]  ->  [[b]]
```

and what I need is `(a -> b) ->  [[a]]  ->  [b]` but I'm not sure where I'm at.

Comment: Reducing all the elements of a potentially long list with a binary operation is the domain of `foldr` (or `foldl'`, if your operation is strict), not `map`.

Comment: `(map) (\[x, y] -> x + y) [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]` would work.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, although my lambda calc can't grasp it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with `map sum` instead. Indeed:

```
Prelude> map sum [[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]
[5,7,9]
```

if you work with `map . map`, it means that you pass a function `f`, such that:

```
(map . map) f [[x11, x12], [x21, x22], [x31, x32]]
```

will yield:

```
[[f x11, f x12], [f x21, f x22], [f x31, f x32]]
```

so you thus map each element in the list of lists. But here you want to sum up the individual elements, so you use [**`sum :: Num a => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:sum) as mapping function.

Comment: Yes, I see how the `(map . map)` will not work. Is there no way to duplicate `sum` in an anonymous function? Not critical, just curious.

Comment: @147pm: `sum = foldr (+) 0`, or you can work with a lambda expression `\x -> sum x`, but I don't see why you need to pass an anonymous function.